# Mantaining component state when changing component placement

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My problem is the following: I have a `InnerComp` which can be placed in two different positions inside the JSX structure, and its position depends on a variable `place`.

What I need is that, when the parent component changes the position of `InnerComp`, the current state (and I mean non just the inner state of the component, but the other children rendered, anything related to it) remains the same.

The only idea I had was to saving the `InnerComp` into a `useRef`, but it doesn't seem to work. 
Let me show you an example in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-smoke-3risy
Now, follow these steps:

1. If you click **increase**, you see that the `counter` in the parent component is updated, but the `props.counter` inside the `InnerComp` doesn't acquire the change (ref is not computed on re-render :( );
2. If you click **increase inner**, the `innerCounter` does increase;
3. Then, if you click on **switch place**, the `InnerComp` is rendered in the other position, but the `innerCounter` is back to `0`;

I know I could try to change the HTML TAG structure and change the CSS when I want to change the position (and I'm sure that would work), but unfortunately, in the real REACT application, I would need to over-complicate the structure to make that possible (the two positions are not related like in this example).

I'm completely out of ideas, so here I'm asking a way to achieve this. It would be enough pointing me to a possible way, then I'm gonna try.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve diferente counters on echa component?

Comment: If you mean the inner component and the parent, no. I want the inner component to mantain its inner counter even after its position changes in the DOM

Comment: Yep, you are bit confused i will extend my answer to try to point you in the right way

Comment: The question is you want to update each child state independently? or you want to update parent counter and show parent counter in both childs?

Comment: I had just one `InnerComp`, not twice or more. Anyways, I got the answer, but thanks anyways for  your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding the answer in case anyone else will find this question.

Eventually, I find a solution using `react-reverse-portal` NPM package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-reverse-portal).

Basically, as far as I've understood, it exploits `React.Portal`. What you do is defining once the element that can change its position in the DOM inside a `<portals.InPortal>`, and then you use `<portals.outportal>` to render that element in different places (though, you CANNOT render the same element in different position at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a best case for [React.Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). But I have not used it yet ☹️.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your issue, you don't need a ref, just use same `key`, e.g. like this

```
 {place === true && <InnerComp counter={counter} key={1} />}
  <hr />
 <h2>Place 2</h2>
 {place === false && <InnerComp counter={counter} key={1}/>}
```

Swap the counters now, you will see inner state isn't lost. This is related to reconciliation. I suppose the answer is [here](https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/#lists):

> A key tells React that it should consider an item to be conceptually
>   the same even if it has different positions **inside its parent** element
>   between renders.

Comment: Ok in my sandbox it works, and tomorrow I'll try on my project. Though.. I'm not sure why it works: I mean, I know reconciliation, but shouldn't it work just to compare siblings, useful when you render bunch of elements for example with a `.map()` function?
By working in this case, it seems that the keys are compared across all the react application

Comment: @Jolly maybe because both InnerComps have same parent in this case div with className App

Comment: Uhm.. I asked because I'm not sure it will work on my real project. I'll let you know tomorrow

Comment: @Jolly It seems it compares keys like this within a parent, check answer I think I found related info.